# Browser display nothing when debugging leaflet api file to connect to geoserver

Tags: geoserver, postgresql, leaflet

actually here is url of geoserver on which my map is published:
http://localhost:8081/geoserver/test/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=test:city_limit&styles=&bbox=-114.315796136219,50.842822033593,-113.859905274451,51.2124253170889&width=768&height=622&srs=EPSG:4326&format=application/openlayers

And i have written a html code using leaflet api to connect to geoserver:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>WMS example - Leaflet</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="docs/images/favicon.ico" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://npmcdn.com/leaflet@1.0.0-rc.3/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/leaflet@1.0.0-rc.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

    <style>
        #map {
            width:600px;
            height: 400px;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

<div id='map'></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var map = L.map('map', {
        center: [-17, -67],
        zoom: 3
    });

    var wmsLayer = L.tileLayer.wms('http://localhost:8081/geoserver/web', {
        layers: 'test:city_limit'
    }).addTo(map);

</script>



</body>
</html>
```

[image: Output screenshot]

Comment: please don't mark this questions as duplicate coz i have viewed many question similar to this but none of that solved my problem..

Comment: So please consider it as new one

Comment: If your service it at  http://localhost:8081/geoserver/test/wms why do you use http://localhost:8081/geoserver/web in the Leaflet code?

Comment: oh sorry ....i have edited that already....but nothing happened

Comment: Your map is initialized to z level 3. Are you sure that your city_limit layer is large enough for being visible at that scale? Can you follow http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/180676/problem-in-ubuntu-loading-geoserver-wms-layer-in-local-server-with-leaflet and make that example to work?

Comment: Are you sure that your geoserver is really on the same machine as your client browser? Also, fix your code to show what you've really done. Exact match. Also, what happens if you change the `center` to match the location in your test layer i.e. `center: [-114, 50],`.

Comment: if you open one of the images what does the text inside say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL of the WMS request you included in your example has `EPSG:4326` on it, but Leaflet uses `EPSG:3857` by default (which might not be enabled on your GeoServer).

You will find insights on how to use `EPSG:4326` with Leaflet in the [WMS tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/wms/wms.html)

Comment: thanks sir .....now the map is visible but now to i have to zoom atleast 10 times to view the map.So sir what could be a problem??

Comment: I guess the data of your WMS service is local, and doesn't include some global dataset such as countries or coastlines. In Leaflet, you should `fitBounds` to the extents of your data.

Comment: sir as i am new to leaflet api so i dont know much about it .......could you please explain how to use fitbound or use global dataset

Comment: i want that if i run my code .....map should be automatically displayed and i dont have to zoomm again and again

Comment: Make a new question for that.